# Using RDL files in Web ReportViewer

Tags: reporting-services

I want to use a rdl file with the query information stored in it.  I don't want to have to convert it to a rdlc file.  I have an ASP.NET app that I want to show the report.  I thought I would use a ReportViewer on my page and then have it use the rdl file.  However, I get an error and in researching it appears that I have to convert the file to an rdlc file.  I don't want to strip out the data contained in the report.  How can I show the report to the user by running the rdl report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was the error message and what version of visual studio are you using? I have used the report viewer control with server based (rdl) files before with no problems, you have to make sure that the render mode (or might be report mode) is set to server and not local.